# Integration of an Angular based application in SharePoint Online Framework?

Tags: angularjs, migration, sharepoint-online, spfx

I have an Angular JS Application from a Notes Migration Project in this form:

[image: FileStructure]

There is a lot of content. In general PDF Files and JS files.

[image: Files]

Now I need to know how can I insert this application into a SharePoint Online Modern site.
Do I need to write the entire application new e.g. in React or still use AngularJS in an SPFx file?
Would it be possible to just move the files to a document library and then move it html structure to a modern site editor?

I would very glad if someone could give some hints.

Best regards

Matthias

Answer (score 0):

No you dont have to write your **entire** application again.
But you may have to still create a webpart that can use angularjs as a backbone.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/guidance/migrate-angular-1-x-applications-to-sharepoint-framework

If you have lot of business logic, then it makes sense to re-write your logic.

If you have mostly static HTML, still you have to create an SPFx webpart but you can copy paste your html in a no JS framework webpart and get going.

PDFs will anyhow go into the Document libraries.